# Cloudera manager ubuntu 12.04 repo key issue

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am attempting to install Cloudera manager on ubuntu 12.04. Using the Path B as described in [enter link description here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_b.html)

I have created the *cloudera-manager.list* file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
On running `sudo apt-get update` I get this in the end:

`...
Fetched 4,180 B in 29s (141 B/s)

Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm5 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 327574EE02A818DD`

After some snooping around I found the required key file at [archive.key](http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cm/archive.key)

and I ran: 
`curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cm/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Now on running `sudo apt-get update` I get:

`...
Fetched 198 B in 17s (11 B/s)

Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm5 Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 327574EE02A818DD Cloudera Apt Repository`

Without this step I cannot proceed and install the OS packages from cloudera.

If anyone has had this issue do tell.

Answer (score 0):

Run: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --keyserver-options --recv-keys 327574EE02A818DD`

**Or, when behind a proxy**

1. Go to https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x327574EE02A818DD
2. Save the public key in a file: `key.pub`
3. Then run: `sudo apt-key add key.pub`